# iPhone local notification at particular time

Tags: iphone, notifications

I want to fire a notification at 10PM(irrespective of country) every week. Do i need to use timeZone. Currently I am using below code to fire notification for every week but there how to fire notification exactly at 10PM.

```
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
NSDate* myNewDate = [date dateByAddingTimeInterval:7*24*60*60];    
UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
localNotification.fireDate = myNewDate;
localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
localNotification.repeatInterval = NSWeekCalendarUnit;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
[localNotification release];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would think that setting your fireDate to 22:00 on the day you want to get the notification (rather than "a week from now") would do what you want.  You'll probably want to use `NSCalendar` to do that.

```
NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
NSDate *fireDate = nil;

[dateComponents setDay:3];  // ...or whatever day.
[dateComponents setHour:22];
[dateComponents setMinute:0];

fireDate = [gregorian dateByAddingComponents:dateComponents
                                      toDate:currentDate 
                                     options:0];

[localNotification setFireDate:fireDate];
[dateComponents release];
```

Answer (score 0):

I made these changes and it worked...

```
NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
NSDate *fireDate = nil;

//Getting current Hour
NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:(kCFCalendarUnitHour | kCFCalendarUnitMinute) fromDate:currentDate];
NSInteger hour = [components hour];
NSInteger minute = [components minute];

[dateComponents setDay:7];//After 1 week
[dateComponents setHour:22-hour-1];  //Calculating Remaining time for 10PM && "-1" because i am adding 60 min
[dateComponents setMinute:60-minute];

//Adding remaining time to current Time
fireDate = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateByAddingComponents:dateComponents
                                              toDate:currentDate 
                                             options:0];
[localNotification setFireDate:fireDate];
```