# UILocalNotification asking of users permission

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

I'm using UILocalNotification in my app but it got rejected because I wasn't asking for users consent.

"5.3: Apps that send Push Notifications without first obtaining user consent will be rejected"

I've seen plenty of apps not asking user.  I thought this was only needed for remote push notifications?

Comment: What does your local notification do?

Comment: Try look at this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10191006/objective-c-detect-when-user-change-the-apps-notifications-settings

Hope will be a useful

Comment: That Technical Note TN2265 seems to be referring to remote notifications.  If I do need to have dialog box popup to get users consent, how do I do this with Local Notifications? I thought iOS handles all this?

Answer (score 0):

That is very odd. I would appeal the rejection and remind them that you aren't using push notifications. Also, double-check your code to make sure that you didn't reference any push notifications then forgot about them.

Answer (score 0):

This does not break any Apple regulations.  I can only imagine two reasons:

1. It was an error by Apple.
2. Your Local Notification is specifically doing something that the user should be approving. EDIT: Now that I know what they do, just make sure that you tell your user that you will be alerted once a week.  Perhaps even make them agree to it first (ex. an option for them to check off in settings).  Although not telling them should still be within the rules, it makes sure that there is no reason for Apple to reject it.

Either way, you should definately appeal the rejection with Apple and remind them that you are using Local Notifications, not Push Notifications.

Comment: I just remind user once a week .."Practice makes perfect!"..my app is an educational app.

I'm basically using this code:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8713110/iphone-local-notification-at-particular-time

Comment: Just make sure that you tell your user that you will be alerted once a week. Although not telling them should still be within the rules, it makes sure that there is no reason for Apple to reject it. And either way, appeal it.

Comment: No response from Apple so I've decided to remove all.  Even though I ripped out all the code and rebooted device, app is still appearing in the Notifications settings "In Notification Center". How is this possible? Im using iOS 5.0 and 5.1 hardware devices.

Comment: I also tried adding [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];  still no luck removing notifications.  I'm losing my mind on this.

Comment: Try "Clean"ing your app. It's under Product > Clean